Current transformer core sizing and selection
Thinking I know the most about inductors and transformers, again I am confused about how to select and size a transformer core. I needed to make a quick 30A current transformer. I tried to calculate the saturation current and concluded that the core must be quite large. But I know from experience that the off-the-shelf CTs for similar current ratings are significantly smaller.
I did some research and took as an example the Coilcraft CST2010 current transformer, which has a core size of about E 13/7/4. From the inductance given in the CST2010 datasheet I calculated the  inductance factor AL. The material is probably something like N87, which has a flux density of 490mT at 25°C. The effective cross section is 12.4mm2 for E 13/7/4. Considering that the primary winding is one turn, the inductance is 850nH. If we enter this information into the magnetic core saturation calculator on "pigeonsnest", the result is a current of approx. 7A. I would like to know if I am calculating something wrong or if Coilcraft is using some exotic material. How does Coilcraft achieve the maximum current of 47A?
TDK E13/7/4 (EF12.6) N87 material ferrite core characteristics
AL = L/N^2 = 850nH/N^2
BS = 490mT @25°C
Ae = 12.4mm2


A good current transformer approximates an ideal transformer. Have you considered the effect of secondary current? Load impedance?

You never run a CT anywhere close to core saturation.
The burden resistor's effect on the primary ensures that.
You have calculated that around 7 amps is needed to saturate the core but, that is the primary magnetization current when the secondary is open-circuit (no burden resistor).
CTs are not meant to be run open-circuit.
The 850 nH primary inductance has a reactance at the operating frequency that is many, many times higher than the burden resistor impedance referred from secondary to primary.
That is how CTs are meant to operate.
The CST2010 CT may be operating at 100 kHz (about mid-range) and that would produce a magnetization reactance of 100,000 x π x 2 x 0.85 /1000000 = 0.53 Ω. If you are using the 1:100 version, the burden resistance when referred to the primary will be 10,000 times smaller. The data sheet tells you that the burden resistor for this particular CT is 2.5 Ω.
This produces a referred burden impedance at the primary of 250 μΩ. This is in parallel with the magnetization reactance of 0.53 Ω. Ask yourself where the primary current flows and you'll see that you won't get any measure of core saturation when the primary current is 47 amps.

Now I understand what the following line in the datasheet means:
"Varying terminating resistance increases or decreases output Voltage/Ampere according to the following equation: RT = Vout × Nsec / Iin."

There is a very good application note from Texas Instruments. TI Literature Number: SLUP114
